802.11n USB wifi adapter (LM Technologies LM816-0648-3 Realtek 00E04C0001) crashes system
I have a desktop running Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS with kernel 6.2.0-1018-lowlatency,
with an LM Technologies LM816-0648-3 Realtek 00E04C0001 802.11n NIC USB wifi adapter.
Wifi use locks the system (display, mouse, keyboard unresponsive). By default the r8188eu driver was loaded (via dmesg), but I see the same behavior with the rtl8188fu driver.
How do I get a stable wifi connection on this device, while ensuring the machine does not crash?

Attempted resolution
It's not a driver conflict: On my system lsmod showed both r8152 and r8188eu drivers active (r8152 for the motherboard ethernet not needed). I ran rmmod r8152 and added blacklist r8152 to  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf; The r8152 driver is no longer active, but wifi use still crashes my system.
It's not a coincidence: I've since run the machine for a few hours without the adapter attached; It remains responsive. Restoring the adapter and using wifi data again locks the system.
The rtl8188fu driver gives similar behavior: I tested the rtl8188fu driver following these installation steps. The behavior is the same.
Related questions etc. that don't resolve this:
Many questions deal with adapters not working, rather than locking the system. Few mention this device;
Many concern support for internal/onboard wifi chipsets, but it's hard to determine which apply to this USB wifi device in June of 2024.
This question has the same symptoms but I don't understand the answer;
This unanswered question reports a kernel panic on an rπ with the same USB adapter, unclear if related;
This open issue on the rtl8188eu driver github seems similar but has no follow-up.

what does dmesg show?

That a Realtek USB 802.11n with serial number 00E04C0001 was added successfully and is using driver r8188eu (or I suppose rtl8188fu after I switched to that). No errors appear there as far as I can tell, unless they appear at the time the system locks up and are cleared on reboot.

Well the only thing that comes into my mind is to try to load the driver with different options to prevent the lockups

I think the problem is power management features. I recommend turning them off.
You can try the following:
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf
echo "options rtl8188fu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf


Thank you; my rtl8188fu.conf already contains this, as well as the setting rtw_ips_mode=0 (presumably a hopeful, but unsuccessful fix, found in an earlier answer).
